# Excecuting combineByKey transformation on an RDD giving Exception. Spark Transformation

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to generate customer statistics using the following code. It's a combineByKey transformation. I got an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception. Wondering for the reason, but I am not getting any hint. Please can anyone clarify, why I am getting this exception. Thank you.

```
def createComb = (t:Array[String]) => {
val total = t(5).toDouble
val q = t(4).toInt
(total/q, total/q, q, total)}

def mergeValues : ((Double,Double,Int,Double), Array[String]) =>
(Double,Double,Int,Double) = 
{case((mx,mn,q,tot),t) =>{
val total = t(5).toDouble
val quan = t(4).toInt
val mxx = scala.math.max(mx, total/q)
val minn = scala.math.min(mn, total/q)
(mxx,minn,quan+q,total+tot)}}

def mergeComb:((Double,Double,Int,Double),(Double,Double,Int,Double)) =>
(Double,Double,Int,Double) = 
{ case((mx1,mn1,q1,tot1),(mx2,mn2,q2,tot2)) =>
(scala.math.max(mx1,mx2), scala.math.min(mn1,mn2), q1+q2, tot1+tot2)}

val statsOfCust = productsTotalByKey.combineByKey(createComb, mergeValues, mergeComb, new org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner(productsTotalByKey.partitions.size))
```

Here is the output which I got when executed on an RDD after executing above code on spark cluster.

```
scala> statsOfCust.first
[Stage 22:>                                                         (0 + 1) / 2]18/11/17 21:26:31 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 22.0 (TID 26, wn01.itversity.com, executor 9): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at $line80.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$createComb$1.apply(<console>:24)
    at $line80.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$createComb$1.apply(<console>:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter$$anonfun$5.apply(ExternalSorter.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter$$anonfun$5.apply(ExternalSorter.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.AppendOnlyMap.changeValue(AppendOnlyMap.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.SizeTrackingAppendOnlyMap.changeValue(SizeTrackingAppendOnlyMap.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1587)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1820)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1769)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1758)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2034)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2055)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2074)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1358)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1331)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$first$1.apply(RDD.scala:1372)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.first(RDD.scala:1371)
  ... 49 elided
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
  at $anonfun$createComb$1.apply(<console>:24)
  at $anonfun$createComb$1.apply(<console>:23)
  at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter$$anonfun$5.apply(ExternalSorter.scala:189)
  at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter$$anonfun$5.apply(ExternalSorter.scala:188)
  at org.apache.spark.util.collection.AppendOnlyMap.changeValue(AppendOnlyMap.scala:144)
  at org.apache.spark.util.collection.SizeTrackingAppendOnlyMap.changeValue(SizeTrackingAppendOnlyMap.scala:32)
  at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:194)
  at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:63)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a problem with `createComb` methods were you are assuming that t array has at least 6 elements.

It is just a quick geuss. Let me know if it helps. If not, I will try to investigate it further :)

Comment: Yeah, I was passing wrong RDD for combineByKey transformation. Thanks!